# Lookup table not working in training data of Rasa NLU

Tags: nlp, markdown, rasa-nlu

I have examples for a particular intent also showing the entity, and I want the model to recognize other words which could be entities for that particular intent, but it fails to recognize it.

```
## intent: frequency
* what is the frequency of [region](field)?
* what's the frequency of[region](field)?
* frequency of [region](field)?
* [region](field)s frequency?
* [region](field) frequency?
* frequency [region](field)?

## lookup: field
* price
* phone type
* region
```

So when I enter the text "What is the frequency of region?" I get the output

```
{'intent': {'name': 'frequency', 'confidence': 0.9517087936401367},
'entities': [{'start': 17, 'end': 23, 'value': 'region', 
'entity': 'field', 'confidence': 0.9427971487440825, 
'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor'}], 'text': 'What is the frequency of region?'}
```

but when I enter the text "What is the frequency of price?" I get the output

```
{'intent': {'name': 'frequency', 'confidence': 0.9276150465011597},
'entities': [], 'text': 'What is the frequency of price?'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to RasaNLU documentation, in order for lookups to work, you need to include a few examples from the lookup table.

Also, you need to understand that "phone type" and "region" are different patterns because "phone type" has two words and "region" is a single word. Keeping this in mind I have extended your dataset as

```
## intent: frequency
* what is the frequency of [region](field)?
* what is the frequency of [city](field)?
* what is the frequency of [work](field)?
* what's the frequency of [phone type](field)?
* what is the frequency of [phone type](field)?
* frequency of [region](field)?
* frequency of [phone type](field)?
* [region](field)s frequency?
* [region](field) frequency?
* frequency [region](field)?
```

Now when I tried all the examples you mentioned they worked even though the "price" was not included in the dataset but the patters were all covered.

```
Enter a message: What is the frequency of price?
{
  "intent": {
    "name": "frequency",
    "confidence": 0.966820478439331
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "start": 25,
      "end": 30,
      "value": "price",
      "entity": "field",
      "confidence": 0.7227365687405007,
      "extractor": "CRFEntityExtractor"
    }
  ]
}
```

I recommend using https://github.com/rodrigopivi/Chatito for generating simple dataset it would make things easier for you and generate synonyms etc. automatically.

Also, just in case you don't know you can also use files to point to large lookups such as

```
## lookup:city
  data/lookups/city_lookup.txt
```

Comment: If we give a file for lookups would we still need to add examples for every lookup?

Comment: Files are just an alternative to the list, so the functionality is the same but it is useful when you have large lookups. I used lookups for city and state and adding a few examples is enough to get rasa to do its job.

Comment: I have tried and it seems unless there is at least one example of a lookup it won't detect it. If this is the case then lookup table's are rendered useless since we need to write down a example anyway for every different entity value.

Comment: My city and state examples worked pretty well ... there are more than 3k cities in the lookup table and I have to only add examples for 10 to 20 ... it feels it's not that useless ...

Comment: What pipeline are you using tensorflow or spacy? It might be working because your are using spacy. I am using tensorflow and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I am using "supervised_embeddings" so I don't think it is related to the pre-trained learner. Lookups are mostly for supervised_embeddings because if you use spacy it would automatically understand the city and state but provides you both in the same variable of location. So there is no difference between NYC and NY when I used spacy, therefore I fallback to supervised_embeddings and used lookups and online available city and state JSON (later converted into text files) to get things working.

Comment: Using standard config (out of the box), rasa lookup tables began to give results when I included several examples using the entities in the lookup (only a small fraction of the whole table) ex."what is the frequency of", and for several different cases ex.''frequency of" in the same intent.

Answer (score 0):

use the following pipeline in the config.yml

pipeline:

- name: WhitespaceTokenizer
- name: RegexFeaturizer
- name: CRFEntityExtractor
- name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  analyzer: "char_wb"
  min_ngram: 1
  max_ngram: 4
- name: DIETClassifier
  entity_recognition: False
  epochs: 100
- name: EntitySynonymMapper
- name: ResponseSelector
  epochs: 100